# @Value doesn't get resolved when called from JSP's or non @Controller classes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am facing this problem where I am trying to use @Value

```
@Value("${message}")
private String message;
```

So string message is getting happily resolved in classes where I am using @Controller annotation along with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{locale}/sandbox", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

However, when I use in a class which is getting called from a JSP page, it doesn't get resolved. I am not using any XML like application-context/servlet.context.xml etc. Rather than that I am using WebAppInitializer

```
@Slf4j
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  

servletAppContext.register(SpringInitializer.class);

registerListener(servletContext, new ContextLoaderListener(servletAppContext));

registerServlet(servletContext, new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext), "/").setLoadOnStartup(1);

}
```

Also I have defined this bean for reading the property file

```
@Configuration
public class DevPropertyReader {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { new ClassPathResource("properties/application-dev.properties") };
    ppc.setLocations(resources);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
    }
}
```

After reading few posts, I came across that property place holder should be defined in servlet-context and dispatcher-servlet too. Not sure if thats the solution, but if it is then how to implement it in WebAppInitializer and should not the @Bean with @Component should have been available everywhere ?

Comment: what do you mean when you say _However, when I use in a class which is getting called from a JSP page, it doesn't get resolved._ ? Are you calling a class directly from JSP?

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="productData" class="com.belmond.utils.ProductDataModel" scope="request"/> so this will create a new instance of class and then calling the method productData.loadProductData(productId, language, response, request);

Comment: You can't use this approach. The ne bean instance will not be handled by Spring

Comment: Any workaround , ideas ?

Comment: Just use spring and spring managed beans

Comment: But JSP is part of spring project only, it is the view layer. Cant figure an alternative  way of calling a method  from JSP .

Comment: But you are using jsp directives and not spring

Comment: Yes, but the class which I am calling does have service annotation. So shouldn't this be managed by spring container? 
@Service
public class ProductDataModel {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153701/discussion-between-angelo-immediata-and-abhishek-galoda).

Comment: @AngeloImmediata: Was able to fix this problem, see the answer below. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue finally. SO the root cause was that I was trying to access a non spring managed bean as

So to fix this issue aal I had to do was annotate my class with @Service annotation and then use the following code to get instance of spring managed bean rather than creating a new bean via jsp

```
<%@ page import="com.belmond.utils.ProductDataModel"%>
 <%@ page import="org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils"%>
 <%@ page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext"%>


<%
  ApplicationContext context = 
    RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);

   ProductDataModel productData = (ProductDataModel)context.getBean("productDataModel");
  //Where ProductDataModel is the class whose bean I wanted
    %>
```

Now the ${message} using @value annotation is getting resolved

```
  @Slf4j
  @Service
  public class ProductDataModel {
    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;
```

Comment: Which is still bad... Your controller should fill the model you want to use... Don't do things like that in a JSP.

Comment: Yes, I agree but unfortunately, I dont have the controller class with me. It's in a thirdparty jar and then it just redirects to this JSP .  Its an Old Content management system which works very weirdly.

Comment: Then write a `HandlerInterceptor` which extends the model created by the controller.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will have a look. Certainly looks a better solution if I could make it work with HandlerInterceptor.

Comment: Also if this bean is a singleton you can also tell your view resolver to always expose it as a model attribute.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that resolver.setExposedContextBeanNames("myBean"); but it didnt worked.. I will try with HandlerInterceptor. Thanks !!

Comment: Exposing the beans should work, you should be able to then just access them by their name. something like `${productDataModel}` should do the trick.